# how to download from an html link (href) in python?

Tags: python-2.7

how to download movie from a link (that normally start with click ) this is the html code for the download   File in the web page. i am looking to do so in python code as a client that download multiply times the movie but not saving it (just simulating traffic on the web page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have the url:

```
import requests
url="http://....."
response = requests.get(url)
```

You can print the response or parse it:

- response.headers is dict of the headers response.
- content is the content of the response